# Go time.Time error to BigQuery. This field: X is not a record

Tags: go, google-bigquery

I keep getting this error on all the date fields. I have an API that has date fields in multiple formats (Like dd-mm-yyyy). I want to convert it all to a BigQuery TIMESTAMP so there is consistency. I read to use the `bigquery.NullTimestamp` so I made the adjustments from a `time.Time` and returning `time.Time{}` to this BQ null type.

Someone knows what I'm doing wrong?

**Error:**

```
failed with error: {Location: "modified_at"; Message: "This field: modified_at is not a record."; Reason: "invalid"}
```

**Code:**

```golang
type StringDutchDateToTimestamp bigquery.NullTimestamp

type ArticleData struct {
    ModifiedAt         StringDutchDateToTimestamp `json:"modified_at" bigquery:"modified_at"`
    Barcode            string                     `json:"barcode" bigquery:"barcode"`
    PromoStartdate     StringDutchDateToTimestamp `json:"promo_startdate,omitempty" bigquery:"promo_startdate"`
    PromoEnddate       StringDutchDateToTimestamp `json:"promo_enddate,omitempty" bigquery:"promo_enddate"`
}

func (t *StringDutchDateToTimestamp) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    if string(b) == "\"\"" || string(b) == "null" {
        t.Valid = false
        t.Timestamp = time.Time{} // Set Timestamp to a zero time value
        return nil
    }

    var dt string
    if err := json.Unmarshal(b, &dt); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    ts, err := time.Parse("02-01-2006", dt)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    t.Timestamp = ts
    t.Valid = true

    return nil
}

//the insert part in other function:

inserter := b.Dataset.Table(b.ArticleData).Inserter()
    if err := inserter.Put(context.Background(), articles); err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("articledata.inserter.put: %w", err)
    }
```

**Input:**

```json
{
  "modified_at": "28-06-2023",
  "barcode": "1111111180588",
  "promo_startdate": null,
  "promo_enddate": null
}
```

**spew.Dump():**

```
(models.ArticleData) {
 ModifiedAt: (models.StringDutchDateToTimestamp) {
  Timestamp: (time.Time) 2023-06-28 00:00:00 +0000 UTC,
  Valid: (bool) true
 },
 Barcode: (string) (len=13) "1111111180588",
 PromoStartdate: (models.StringDutchDateToTimestamp) {
  Timestamp: (time.Time) 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC,
  Valid: (bool) false
 },
 PromoEnddate: (models.StringDutchDateToTimestamp) {
  Timestamp: (time.Time) 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC,
  Valid: (bool) false
 }
}
```

**BigQuery schema:**

```
modified_at         NULLABLE    TIMESTAMP   
barcode             NULLABLE    STRING      
promo_startdate     NULLABLE    TIMESTAMP   
promo_enddate       NULLABLE    TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: After investigation, looks like `bigquery.NullTimestamp` and `time.Time` only works as "direct" struct types. So with custom types this is not working. Looks like I need a second struct and a function to convert the origirnal data types to the new one after json.unmarschal?